# Filtering pandas crosstab based on appearances

Tags: python, pandas

I have huge pandas crosstab, I want to filter item that just appear once, to make easier to explain, I will make artificial data, here's my data

```
Customer_id        Apple     Book    Candy
1                  0         1       1
2                  1         1       0
3                  1         1       0
4                  1         0       0
```

Because `Candy` is just appeared once, so the result will be like

```
Customer_id        Apple     Book 
1                  0         1      
2                  1         1       
3                  1         1       
4                  1         0
```

Comment: Do you need count number of `0` per columns?

Comment: give the answer please on comment

Comment: I add both solutions with count unique `1` or count unique `0`, I guess need second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dropna`

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).dropna(axis=1,thresh=2).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[18]: 
   Customer_id  Apple  Book
0            1      0     1
1            2      1     1
2            3      1     1
3            4      1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with boolean mask:

If want filter out with one `1` per columns without first:

```
df = df.set_index('Customer_id')
df = df.loc[:, df.eq(1).sum().ne(1)]
print (df)
             Apple  Book
Customer_id             
1                0     1
2                1     1
3                1     1
4                1     0
```

**Details**:

Compare by `1`:

```
print (df.eq(1))
             Apple   Book  Candy
Customer_id                     
1            False   True   True
2             True   True  False
3             True   True  False
4             True  False  False
```

Count `True`s per columns by `sum`:

```
print (df.eq(1).sum())
Apple    3
Book     3
Candy    1
```

Compare by `1` for not equal:

```
print (df.eq(1).sum().ne(1))
Apple     True
Book      True
Candy    False
dtype: bool
```

---

If want filter only one `0` per columns without first:

```
df = df.set_index('Customer_id')
df = df.loc[:, df.eq(0).sum().eq(1)]
print (df)
             Apple  Book
Customer_id             
1                0     1
2                1     1
3                1     1
4                1     0
```

**Details**:

Compare by `0`:

```
print (df.eq(0))
             Apple   Book  Candy
Customer_id                     
1             True  False  False
2            False  False   True
3            False  False   True
4            False   True   True
```

Count `True`s per columns by `sum`:

```
print (df.eq(0).sum())
Apple    1
Book     1
Candy    3
dtype: int64
```

Compare by `1`:

```
print (df.eq(0).sum().eq(1))
Apple     True
Book      True
Candy    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Is it the number of zeros that need to be counted, or the number of ones?

Comment: @unutbu - I guess `0`, but hard to know. But by expected output seems `0`